# Trying to use UNION on multiple queries but won't work because of my subquery uses AVG

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to basically run 6 select queries(displayed two for the sake of readability but its basically that same pattern) and using union to create a single output. However, when I run the query, I get 2 of the following errors.

- Msg.141 A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operation.
- Msg.10734 Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top-level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

I understand and have looked at similar questions but nothing seems to work.

I would like to have the output look like this

```
|Tabe|Rent|Thd|
---------------------------------
|table1   | 9999      | 8888    |
|table2   | 9999      | 8888    |
```

Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which DBMS is this for, MySQL or SQL Server?  They are different and have different restrictions and solutions for this kind of thing.

Comment: Also, why are you using variable assignment if you want output rows displayed from your SELECT statements?  The first error message is telling you that you cannot do both in the same sql statement.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the tags, to just be SQL server. I'm using the variable assignment because I needed something hold the @Threshold calculation number to display in the table. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. I'm still really new to SQL.

Comment: These two messages are pretty clear. So you need to subquery to get the variable. Since you only have two rows guaranteed you can just put them in variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need variables at all here. You need an `OVER` clause to calculate the average over all the rows:

```sql
Select
    'table1' as TableName,
    count(*) as RecordCount,
    0.75 * AVG(count(*)) over ()
from table1
where @something = specificDate
group by specificDate

union all

Select
    'table2',
    count(*) as RecordCount,
    0.75 * AVG(count(*)) over ()
from table2
where @something = specificDate
group by specificDate;
```

I note that your query appears to be filtering on `specificdate`. SO you can just group by the empty set: `group by ()`

Comment: This is great! Thanks a ton!